# magento not following .htaccess rule

Tags: magento-1.9, htaccess, 301-redirect

have a magento site i click on all links and they rewrite fine. Only one issue, I have some links that look like this assume my domain name is somesite.com

http://www.somesite.com/?htm/147 and i want it to redirect to http://www.somesite.com/someplace/ of course homesite is replaced with my real domain. assume i am using https://github.com/nexcess/magento/blob/master/.htaccess.sample renamed to .htaccess

i add this to .htaccess but it has no affect

Redirect 301 /?htm/147 http://www.somesite.com/someplace/ ideas?

Comment: What is "someplace", in this case? Is that a category/product list page? Or is that a custom CMS page?

Comment: Have you enabled rewrites in Magento System Config?

Comment: I'd suggest having custom rewrites setup in Magento admin, not in htaccess. They are much more manageable.

Answer (score 1):

In your `.htaccess` the following should work:
`Redirect 301 /?htm/147 /someplace`

You could also look at using a rewrite match
`redirectMatch 301 ^/?htm/147/?$  /someplace/`

If you're going from someplace.com to someplace.net you would need to setup the following:

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^someplace.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.someplace.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://someplace.net/$1 [L,R=301,NC]`

Hope this helps.